# Json schema not working without `$schema` tag in json file itself

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm trying to get the JSON schema validation to work without specifying the `"$schema"` property in json file itself, similar to what happens in the playground example, following the steps mentioned in [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.40.0#example-extending-language-services-configure-json-defaults) but not able to get it working as expected.

Tyring to integrate it in a react app based on Vite, & initializing the workers in a separate file, & in the same file making adding any other code editor config.

---

[App with issue](https://editors-ten.vercel.app) | [Configuration](https://github.com/himanshupal/editors/blob/dev/src/workers.ts)

---

I was expecting it provide me hover suggestions on json file, like it works currently if I use the same schema uri from the config in current file's `"$schema"` property.